# Set up a Bazaar SmartServer without ssh on windows server 2008

Tags: version-control, windows-server-2008, dvcs, windows-server-2008-r2, bazaar

How can I set up a [Bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/en/) smart server on windows server using the Bazaar protocol only (aka **bzr://** and no **ssh**)? **Although** I must still have a user/password authentication.

It is hard to find the right documentation or even the right information indicating whether there is a possibility to do that or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Available Bazaar protocol for authentication with username & password : **FTP, SFTP, HTTP,  HTTPS.**

the `bzr://` protocol does **not** support authentication.

Have a look here:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/developers/authentication-ring.html

Comment: Man that's the answer I was afraid of... Thank you very much, I might go with SFTP then.

Comment: Bear in mind that SFTP is *not* a smart protocol. Smart protocol requires a bzr server running on the remote end and I believe that is only possible with the HTTP(S), SSH and bzr protocols.

Comment: More information: http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/http_smart_server.html

Comment: @dOxxx Exact! according to the following page, smart server is limited to **SHH, BZR and inetd (bzr)** .
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/server.html